# How to access mysql database at multiple sites without using remote jdbc connection

Tags: mysql, web-services, jdbc, resultset, remote-access

The idea to access multiple remote mysql databases some 30 in numbers using remote jdbc connection in my java application  has been ruled out by the DBA's. No remote connection is permitted to the respective mysql DB. Connection can only be allowed from the local j2ee app servers within the LAN.

Alternatives suggested are :
1) Using a Middle ware Messaging layer which invoke some java at the remote side to provide the database results.

2) Using a Web Service on the remote MySQL database site as these site have J2EE App Servers to return the database query results. However i understand that the JDBC resultset cannot be serialized in a web service call and needs to be handled separately.

As the requirement is that the web service call will be using and SQL Query and the Result is to be returned to the Client. How efficiently this can be achieved.

Thinking of what other options are available.

Regards

Pramod.

Comment: What do your DBAs say to accessing the server through an ssh tunnel?

Comment: DBA is not agreeing to permitting any sort of remote connection even ssh.